# Excel VBA extract date from CSV txt

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm having trouble extracting this text, exactly as it appears, from a CSV. There are similar questions posted on SO but they don't match my requirements:

I want to extract "31 January 2017" from this row:

```
4,'31 January 2017','Funds Received/Credits',56,,401.45,
```

Currently, VBA considers it "31 Jan" without the year. I've tried applying .NumberFormat to the cell (general, text, date).

SOLUTION REQUIREMENTS:

1. No user action required -- Interact with the file only using VBA (not using File > Import > Wizard)
2. Compatible with VBA Excel 2003
3. Extract the full text regardless of Excel or operating system date settings

Thank you for your ideas

Comment: Edit your question to show your VBA code.

Comment: braX's answer is the easiest, most straight-forward and gives exactly the desired result, so I've selected it.

Further troubleshooting on my issue reveals that Excel was, in fact, giving the correct result -- I was comparing the output to the wrong row.  Face palm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the split function, using the comma as a delimiter like this:

```
sResult = Split("4,'31 January 2017','Funds Received/Credits',56,,401.45, ", ",")(1)
```

If you dont want the single quotes, then add the replace function like this:

```
sResult = Replace(Split("4,'31 January 2017','Funds Received/Credits',56,,401.45, ", ",")(1), "'", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you include the "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" Reference, you can set up a pattern that will extract the whole date if it is found. For example:

```
Dim tstring As String
Dim myregexp As RegExp
Dim StrMatch As Object
tstring = 'Line from the CSV, or entire CSV as one string
Set myregexp = New RegExp
myregexp.Pattern = "\d{1,2} [A-Z]{3,9} \d{4}"
Set StrMatch = myregexp.Execute(tstring)
```

You get the benefit from this method that all the dates in the CSV will be pulled out at once, much faster than using a split line by line. Additionally, the dates may be accessed by using

```
DateStr = StrMatch.Item(index)
```

for the whole string line, or substrings can be set up to get specific parts of the string(Such as month, day, year).

```
myregexp.Pattern = "\(d{1,2}) ([A-Z]{3,9}) (\d{4})"
Set StrMatch = myregexp.Execute(tstring)
DateStr = StrMatch.Item(index1).SubMatches(index2)
```

It is a very powerful tool, with a simple set of symbols for development of patterns. I highly suggest you familiarize yourself with it for manipulation of large strings.